# Search root in search.php in a subdirectory wordpress installation

Tags: php, wordpress, search, root, subdirectory

I have a wordpress install in a subdirectory, but the search function will not work unless I manually include the root directory. How would I change the code in search.php to accomplish a full site search?

Here's the standard code:

```
<form class="art-search" method="get" name="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( site_url() ); ?>/">
    <input name="s" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_search_query()); ?>" />
    <input class="art-search-button" type="submit" value="" />
</form>
```

I need the search feature to jump up one directory and search the entire root.  The WP directory is in subdirectory "new" so currently search executes:

```
(site)/new/?s=test *but does not return results.*
```

If the sub is removed:

```
(site)/?s=test *returns all results.*
```

I'm sure this is an easy fix, but I haven't figured it out.

Thanks in advance,
Jason

Answer (score 0):

Well, in case anyone is wondering, the solution turns out to be changing "site_url" to "home_url."